# Renaming a File

Tags: java

In my application there is a file available that
 Say **one.pdf**. I want to change the file name as **two.pdf** with in the same directory.

i tried using java which doesn't Work.

```
File f1=new File("E:\\one.pdf");
File f2=new File("E:\\two.pdf");
f1.renameTo(f2);
```

Comment: What error do you get? Be more specific please

Comment: I have already tried this i am not getting error. if you get than give error detail.

Comment: May be you have already a file with this name in the same directory..(two.pdf)

Comment: Maybe you are trying to run same program again and again and your file got renamed already.

Comment: Sorry Guys. I have messed up a lil bit. I missed one Space in file name..
Anyway thanks for your support

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions? Try doing `System.out.println("Can write to file: " + f1.canWrite());` and `System.out.println("Can write to directory: " + f2.getParentFile().canWrite());`

Answer (score 2):

Your Code has a significant error:

You do not check the result of [File#renameTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29). The renaming may fail, if you have UAC activated or the destination is invalid.

```
public class Rename {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f1=new File("c:\\tools\\one.pdf");
        File f2=new File("c:\\tools\\two.pdf");
        try{
            boolean result = f1.renameTo(f2);
            System.out.println("worked? " + result);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see the problem with your code unless this is some sort of Windows path thing or a permissions issue.  As mentioned in comments, you should always show the exceptions or error results.

One thing to consider would be to better use the existing `File` object to rename the file in the same directory:

```
// someExistingFile defined above
File destinationFile = new File(someExistingFile.getParentFile(), "two.pdf");
someExistingFile.renameTo(destinationFile);
```

This will use the directory of the existing file and create the new file relative to it.